# Eror en la conexion a una DB en visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-basic

El roblema es que me detecta solo un error:

Error BC30909 `cnn` no puede exponer el tipo `SqlConnection` fuera del proyecto a través de class `conexión`. SistemaDeVentas `C:\Users\Raibel mejia\Desktop\N\DASI pepelo\SistemaDeVentas\SistemaDeVentas\Datos\Conexion.vb`

Estoy creando un pequeño sistema de ventas y estoy haciendo la conexión a la base de datos dbventas en Sqlserver y me detecto ese error, aquí el código para que lo puedan ver:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient ( so me aparece en gris y no se porque)

Conexión de Clase Pública

Protected cnn As SqlConnection

Public idusuario As Integer

Protected Function conectado()
    Try
        cnn = New SqlConnection("data source=LAPTOP-DE-RAIBE;initial catalog=dbventas;integrated security=true")
        cnn.Open()
        Return False

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try

End Function

Protected Function desconectado()
    Try
        If cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Close()
            Return True

        Else

            Return False

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False

    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tenes todos los paquetes instalados?? esta en gris, porque no lo estas usando ese paquete... porque esto "Protected cnn As SqlConnection
" porque es protected?? todo tu problema esta ahi